# Apache Cassandra install guide

Tags: database, cassandra

I'm trying to find cassandra instalation guide and all I've found is installing  guide of apache-cassandra-0.6.6 version, I have the latest apache cassandra 2.0.2 version binary files and doesn't include some of the included config files which previous version had. so please can you tell me how to install apache cassandra 2.0.2?

Comment: In which OS you want to install ?

Comment: then follow the link in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to install `DataStax Community` edition. Currently `DataStax` distributes and supports `Cassandra`. You can find all `Cassandra` documentation [Here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/gettingstarted/index.html?pagename=docs&version=quick_start&file=quickstart#getting_started/gettingStartedIntro_r.html#reference_ds_gpq_1gs_jk)

To install `DataStax Community` edition on various platform (such as - `RHEL, Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS, Mac X, Windows, any Linux distribution` etc.),  use [THIS](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/gettingstarted/index.html?pagename=docs&version=quick_start&file=quickstart#getting_started/gsInstallIndex.html) link.